# Trying to use IIS Express with MVC2 Webform Hybrid Application

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, webforms, iis-express, hybrid

I am working on a Web application that is a Hybrid of Webforms and MVC2. (using .Net 3.5)

So far I have been developing using the Visual Studio web server but am trying to switch to use the IIS Express server provided within Visual Studio 2010.

When I run the application in IIS Express the Webforms are fine but when I try to navigate to an MVC page I get 404 errors.

This is working fine with the Visual Studio Webserver.

Any ideas on how to configure IIS Express - lots of googling so far and nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have done some further searching on this and found the answer on the following blog:
[MvcRouting](http://www.beletsky.net/2011/10/integrating-aspnet-mvc-into-legacy-web.html%20MVCRouting)

About halfway down this blog there is a section about adding URL Routing Modules and Handlers.  This solved the problem.  I also had to add the session bits at the bottom of the post.

Solved! :-))